# backbone handlebars and requirejs: handlebars returns a function instead of html

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, handlebars.js

This is my simple BackboneView when I try to load the widget.tpl.
However the template var contains a function()

What do I do wrong ?

```
define(['hbs!templates/widget'],function (template) {
var template = Handlebars.compile( template );
console.log(template);

MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        // Compile the template using Handlebars

       console.log(template);
        //this.el.html( template );
    }
});
    return MyView;
});
```

widget.tpl has

```
<div>helloworld</div>
```

Comment: Is not the standard behaviour? Try `console.log(template())`.

Comment: `Handlebars.compile` converts a template with place holders into a function to which one can execute with the parameters for the placeholders to get the desired HTML.

Comment: Did my answer help or are you still needing assistance?

Answer (score 1):

Careful not to redefine the `template` variable. The `hbs` plugin returns the compiled Handlebars function, [as you can see in the docs](https://github.com/SlexAxton/require-handlebars-plugin). It would probably be better like this:

```
define(['hbs!templates/widget'],function (template) {
    console.log(template); // -> logs compiled Handlebars template function

    var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
        render: function(){
            // Compile the template using Handlebars
            this.$el.append(template());
            return this;
        }
    });
    return MyView;
});
```

Also, you probably don't want to render the view in initialize. Initialize should only set up your view; rendering within initialize introduces unwanted side effects when creating an instance. Somewhere else in your code you'll have this:

```
var MyView = require('MyView');
var view = new MyView();
$('body').append(view.render().el);
```